# PHP - hashing passwords with bcrypt

Tags: php, bcrypt, php-password-hash

I have question about valid hashing passwords:

## **login.php**

```
$login = $_POST['login'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$hash = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
if(!empty($login) && !empty($password) && password_verify(??){
```

I want to make secure login and I know that I have to verify the inputted password with existing hash (stored in database?). Also I know that bcrypt everytime makes new hash (because of different salt size etc).

The problem is that I don't know how to put this hash into database because I don't want to register new users, I have static list of users (exactly two: admin and user).

I tried manually copy/paste hash but it wouldn't work as I mentioned earlier that every time I run script new hash is created.

Can anyone help me how to put bcrypt hash in database (only once) so I can only check if inputted password is same as the one in database?

Do I need extra variables to store this hash?

**EDIT:**

## **login.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
include("log.php");
include("pdo.php");
$login = $_POST['login'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

$adminHash = '$2y$10$lxPRtzzPDUZuPlodhU4QquP.IBrGpkjMNplpNgN9S1fEKd64tJ5vm';
$userHash = '$2y$10$Klt345wT66vA.4OAN5PEUeFqvhPQJ4Ua/A4Ylpc1ZcnJZv/hafgSu';

if(!empty($login) && !empty($password) && (password_verify($password, $adminHash) || password_verify($password, $userHash))){
    $query = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM xx WHERE login = ? AND admin = ?');
    $query->execute(array( $login, 1));
    $result = $query->fetchAll();
    if(!empty($result)) {
        $_SESSION['logged_admin'] = 1;
    }
    else {
        $query->execute(array( $login, 0));
        $result = $query->fetchAll();
        if(!empty($result)) {
            $_SESSION['logged_user'] = 1;
        }
        else {
            $_SESSION['logged_error'] = 1;
        }
    }
}
else $_SESSION['logged_error'] = 1;
header("Location:index.php");

?>
```

it seems to be working but i dont know if it's best/safest solution.
With more passwords it will be too complicated i guess, still looking for best option!
What if i need more users? now every user have same hash and it's dangerous i get it, how to make it safe? generate hash for every user and make array or hashes?

Comment: Just store the hash wherever you store the static user list, and then compare the submitted password with the hash using password_verify

Comment: I think this post describes the best way to go about this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4795385/how-do-you-use-bcrypt-for-hashing-passwords-in-php/6337021#6337021

Comment: @JimL thanks for answer, you mean storing it in script? when i said about static list of users i was talking about database. Where should i store that kind of information? any idea?

Comment: @ChristopherHughes so if i want to have 10 users i need store 10 hashes? and also i need to password_verify with everyone of them? i know there is better answer for this.

Comment: @dmnmlk if you have the users in the databse then add the hashes to the same table

Answer (score 1):

You fetch first the one that has password_hash() from your database, and then compare it with password_verify($password, $storedpassword) like this : [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54264404/why-json-encode-create-new-line-after-password-verify-php-and-create-error-in-an)